# How to get the error log from SASS when using the rails asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, sass, asset-pipeline, sprockets

I've got 3 Rails 3.2 applications using the gem jquery-ui-themes.   jquery-ui-themes uses scss for the image-path helper.

It works great on two of my applications, but the 3rd doesn't seem to compile the scss files in either development or production modes.

IOW, it sends this to the browser

```
 background: #fcfdfd url(image-path("jquery-ui/redmond/ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png")) 50% bottom repeat-x;
```

whereas the two working apps properly send

```
 background: #fcfdfd url("/assets/jquery-ui/redmond/ui-bg_inset-hard_100_fcfdfd_1x100.png") 50% bottom repeat-x;
```

I've spent many hours trying to make the app that's broken as similar to possible to the two working apps as I can, but it's still failing.

My theory is that SASS is choking on something previous to redmond.css.scss.   If so, there should be an error logged somewhere.   Where do I find the error output from SASS?

#### Update:

I introduced a deliberate error into redmond.css.scss and I got a proper error dump.   So I know that I'm correctly clearing the cache and actually running sass.   Now to figure out why it's ignoring the image-path directives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking for the answer for my real problem (image-path not working), make sure you have the proper Bundler.require line in your application.rb.   The old Rails 3.0 doesn't work.

replace:

```
# If you have a Gemfile, require the gems listed there, including any gems
# you've limited to :test, :development, or :production.
Bundler.require(:default, Rails.env) if defined?(Bundler)
```

with:

```
if defined?(Bundler)
  # If you precompile assets before deploying to production, use this line
  Bundler.require(*Rails.groups(:assets => %w(development test)))
  # If you want your assets lazily compiled in production, use this line
  # Bundler.require(:default, :assets, Rails.env)
end
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking for the answer to the question in the title, the answer is "the same way you get any other errors:  they're in your log".   To get a full backtrace, just point your browser at the asset:  ie `http://localhost:3000/assets/jquery-ui/redmond.css` in my case.

Make sure you clear all your caches:  `rm -rf .sass-cache/ && rm -rf public/assets && rake tmp:cache:clear`, as well as using ctrl-shift-r in your browser.

Comment: Why would you tell people to "rm -rf public/assets"??  Isn't this potentially going to delete their own files?